# Launching a Console Applications from a MenuStrip (Visual C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to have a Windows Form Application use a menustrip with three options to launch a console application. The console application is a .exe file built in C# in Visual Studio with some basic code for as school project. The console application does not need to return any values, it only needs to run and allow the user to use it. This is what the form will look like: [Menu Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHDHF.png)

I have tried importing the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` namespace with `Process.Start@("Path of file")` in my menu item click event method to launch my C# console application but have not been successful. I am getting a *"Win32Exception was unhandled: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll. Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified"*

Here is the code in the menu item click event:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void lesson13LabCToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {

    Process.Start(@"\C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\LabMenu\LabMenu\Lesson13LabC.exe");
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear `The system cannot find the file specified`. Check the path of file.

Also remove the starting `\` in the path

Answer (score 0):

Remove the backslash at the beginning of your path (before the drive letter).

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Just a simple solution. This had me caught up for so long! Ughhh!